# Nodejs export module keys error keys.js:1 ��m

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

hola esoy tratando de crear un pool a mi bd desde un app de express

me da este error

```
    [nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
C:\Users\erpre\Documents\Work\steamvideoapp\src\keys.js:1
��m


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\erpre\Documents\Work\steamvideoapp\src\databse.js:5:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

aqui es donde genero mi bd y mi keys

keys.js

```
module.exports = {
database: {
    host: 'mibd.com',
    user: 'miuser',
    password: 'mispass',
    database: 'mibd',
    port:3306
}}
```

esta es mi conexion

```
   const mysql = require('mysql');
const {promisify} = require('util');


const {database} = require('./keys');

const pool = mysql.createPool(database);

pool.getConnection((err,conn)=>{
    if(err){
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'){
            console.log('database connection was closed')
        }
        if(err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR'){
            console.log('database has to many connections')
        }
        if(err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED'){
            console.log('database access denied'+ err)
        } 
    }

    if(conn){
        console.log('connection success /heroku');
        conn.release();
        return;
    }
});



pool.query = promisify(pool.query)

module.exports = pool;
```

y aqui la llamo el error esta en el **pool**

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const pool = require('../databse');

router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('links/add');
});

module.exports = router
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te arroja estos símbolos en la consola: ��m ? Parece un problema de codificación de tu archivo. Hay probabilidades de que lo hayas editado con algún programa de edición diferente al que usas y que le haya cambiado la codificación. ¿Podrías verificar eso?, yo que tu crearía nuevamente dicho archivo si es posible. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras puedes agregar tu respuesta y te la doy si gustas, en definitva ya no me da ese error